# getting selenium, ghostdriver, phantomJS working on windows 7

Tags: windows, selenium, phantomjs

I am using selenium-2.34 and phantomJS-1.9.1-windows

however when i try to use:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService;
```

I can see that it does not detect

```
org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs
```

getting this error

```
The import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs cannot be resolved
```

I was under the impression that GhostDriver was embedded in PhantomJS - https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver

does anyone know what could be wrong with my setup?

EDIT: Could this be due to a path issue, do i need to supply some way for selenium to pick up these up https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/tree/master/binding/java/src/main/java/org/openqa/selenium/phantomjs

Answer (score 1):

Just add following in your pom.xml (if maven used):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
    <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Or, if maven not used, grab JAR file from here: http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.github.detro.ghostdriver/phantomjsdriver/1.0.3/